# Salesforce Summer'18 Issue in Process with Scheduled Action

Tags: process-builder, customer-community, time-dependent-workflow

We have a process with scheduled action which will create a record in custom object upon completion of a learning course by Customer Community users. This process is working correctly in Spring 18 sandbox but not in Summer’18.

In Summer’18, scheduled action is getting listed in the waiting flows queue and after few seconds clears from the queue presumably after executing action. However, no record is created and there is no debug log for success or failure. No trace of what happened. Same process works perfectly when the action is initiated by other profiles. Issue is happening only for customer community user. We have verified all the profile permissions etc., and this has stopped working in the sandboxes only after Summer'18 upgrade.

We have another scheduled action process to send email notification. This also has same issue.

We have created a support case with Salesforce and working with them but could not get any progress yet. Interestingly, no other customer seems to have reported similar issue.

Do any of you have faced similar issue in Summer'18 sandbox or in the past?
Any workaround suggestions?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved by Salesforce.

We worked with Salesforce R&D team and they were able to triage and rolled out emergency release yesterday to fix this problem in Summer'18 sandboxes. No change was needed from our end.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you per se but  [there are several known issues with time based work flows and scheduled actions](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?search=time%20based).  Sometimes my processes can be a bit buggy when copied from Prod to a sandbox - especially when they're not on the same release.

You might test by creating a test simple process from scratch that mimics the basic functions of your current process and see if it works. If it does, then it's just the sandbox being buggy.

Comment: We tried creating new process from the scratch and even it did not work. Secondly, the processes stopped working only after Summer'18 upgrade.